# Streaming API - update notifications payload

Tags: field-update, configuration, streaming-api

I hope one can help me out answering the following question, as the SF documentation is not precise at this:

I know that based on a topics SOQL query and its specific configuration SF resolves whether to fire a new event or not. I also know that the fields specified in the querys select section will define what fields to include in the JSON payload of such an event. But from my so far experience, an event of type "update" always only contains those fields that have changed. Is it possible to configure (for any) topic to contain the whole object and not only the updated fields?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. This is a performance enhancement, as a single record can easily end up sending a payload of many megabytes, which could cause performance issues in most systems. The client is expected to already have a copy of the record, and thus doesn't need a full update. If you need a full copy, use the relevant REST API call to retrieve the record's contents (preferably with a If-Modified-Since header, again for performance reasons).